# Where does SWIFT ABI come into picture?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-construction, llvm, abi

The title might not be sufficient to give an overview of the question context. So here goes the description:

**SWIFT Compilation process**
The Swift compiler undergoes the following steps to compile a Swift file

[image: Swift compilation steps]

As per [Apple](https://swift.org/compiler-stdlib/#compiler-architecture),

> IR generation (implemented in lib/IRGen) lowers SIL to LLVM IR, at
>   which point LLVM can continue to optimize it and generate machine code.

***Query Number 1 -***  We all know that compiler turns our source code to Assembly Language and Assembler(mostly embedded in OS, at least Swift compiler doesn't have an assembler in it) converts that into Machine code. So as per the quoted statement above, the LLVM in compiler changes the LLVM IR to machine code. ***So if this is the case then the assembler would be having no role to play in a Swift program and execution?***

***Query Number 2 -*** LLVM in Swift changes the LLVM IR directly to machine code. So that means my compiled executable binary has machine code, not assembly code. And as per my understanding machine code doesn't need any specific calling convention as an assembly language has, and ABI is all about calling conventions, memory layout representations, etc via which the communication between two binaries is defined. ***So where does ABI comes in the picture then because the binary executable already has the machine code?***

So is there something I am missing or Apple has kept it quite abstract?

Comment: The difference between assembly and machine code is that assembly is a text format and machine code is binary. It has nothing to do with calling conventions. Also where did you get that assemblers are "mostly embedded in OS"?

Comment: did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface ?

Comment: @sepp2k Yeah, we agree on the fact that machine code has nothing to do with calling conventions. So when iOS apps executable binary gets installed in the OS, why would it require an ABI to communicate with Swift standard library in OS.

"mostly embedded in OS", at least this happens with iOS I can guarantee.

Comment: @Sulthan I did go through that, but I am trying to visually interpret the concepts of ABI correlating with the communication between iOS apps executable binary and the binary of swift standard library embedded in iOS.

Means why do u even need ABI if iOS apps executable contains machine code?

Comment: @G.Abhisek How is function declaration stored in machine code? function names, parameter names, default values, attributes? How does the memory layout of a struct looks like? If a Swift application has to call a function from the standard library (runtime), it has to know how such things are stored. That's the ABI stability of runtime. A library is not just a set of machine code instructions.

Comment: @G.Abhisek I'm saying the difference between assembly and machine code has nothing to do with calling conventions. Whether LLVM produces assembly that is fed into an assembler or whether it emits machine code directly, makes absolutely no difference with regards to calling conventions (or really with regards to anything).

Comment: Also please read https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABIStabilityManifesto.md which provides a nice explanation.

Comment: @Sulthan So putting my questions straight: a)  Does Swift compiler convert source code to Machine code or Assembly? b) So who respects the ABI conventions, the Machine code or Assembly?

Pardon If I am confused

Comment: Assembly is just another type of intermediate code and it's completely irrelevant for ABI. ABI is only necessary during runtime. It's a communication layer for runtime. Or in other words, assembler is a low level programming language. It has probably no place in the Swift compiler, maybe only as intermediate point of translation.

Comment: @sepp2k https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface , says that calling convention is quite an important part of ABI stability. So if the compiled version of my source code(whether the result is Machine code or assembly) does not respect it, so how can I say its ABI stable?

Comment: @Sulthan I think I got this, probably I was confusing between runtime and the applications executable binary. One more query, ABI is only necessary during runtime, i.e when the programs are getting executed in the processor, ABI defines how the processor would store data types. How function calls would be laid out in the stack frame, etc. Am I correct?

Comment: @G.Abhisek It is also needed during linking, e.g. when linking against a static library. The compiler has to know which functions are inside the static library and you need stable ABI for that too. That's why you get an error "Cannot import module compiled by another compiler version" in current Swift compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice description of the role of ABI in [ABI Stability Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABIStabilityManifesto.md).

In summary, ABI is about the communication layer between compiled application modules during linking and runtime. For example the application and a compiled static library. Or the application and the standard library (Swift runtime).

ABI answers the questions like:

- how is a function stored? how is the name stored? how are its parameters stored? How are default parameter values stored? how are attributes (e.g. availability) stored?, how are generics stored? Where do you find the machine instructions for a function?
- how to put parameters on the calling stack before starting executing function machine instructions (that is, how to pass parameters and `self` to a function?). This is what the *calling conventions* is.

If you have two versions of a Swift compiler and each uses a different format, they cannot call each other because they don't know how to interpret the information in the files. That's why ABI stability is needed. It stabilizes the way code is stored. Note that machine instructions are the body of functions but all the other metadata has to be stored too.

Assembly has no role in ABI stability. Assembly is just another low level programming language which is not used in Swift.